# Was Darth Vader originally intended to be an alien instead of a human in a suit?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, darth-vader, behind-the-scenes, george-lucas

I got into a discussion today with somebody about whether Darth Vader was originally supposed to be human. We didn't find an answer, so we're hoping you can.

Is there any very early reference to Darth Vader's species? Is there something from an early draft of the script that says George Lucas intended Darth Vader to be human all along? Or that he considered Vader as non-human until he decided to make him human for a big reveal in *The Empire Strikes Back*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I can determine, it appears that George Lucas always intended to depict Vader as a human.  This can be seen in the Dark Horse Comics miniseries [*The Star Wars,*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars) which is based on the original draft of Lucas' script for what eventually became *A New Hope.*

Here is some concept art for the character's depiction in *The Star Wars,* the comic:

[image: *The Star Wars:* Darth Vader]

There were some other notable changes to the character from the original draft, such as the fact that he originally wasn't a Sith, but a General in the Imperial military:

[image: Darth Vader meets Prince Valorum (1)]

[image: Darth Vader meets Prince Valorum (2)]

You'll also notice in these images that Vader isn't as cybernetic as he is in the final films.  Lucas originally did not envision him as a cyborg.  That came in a later draft of the script, as described here at [starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/from-concept-to-screen-bringing-darth-vader-to-life):

> “Early in the script there was a description of Vader crossing between two ships in space so I created this mask so he could breathe in space, with a suggestion of teeth in the masks [sic] grillwork,” McQuarrie said.  It was not until the fourth draft that Lucas wrote in more of the backstory of Vader, with his connection to Ben Kenobi and Luke’s father, as well as the duel that followed between Ben and Vader after Vader killed Luke’s father. The duel ended with Vader falling into a volcanic pit and needing the suit and mask that Ralph McQuarrie had come up with.

So, while Vader did undergo some changes between his inception to his ultimate depiction in the Original Trilogy, there doesn't seem to be anything to indicate that Lucas ever planned for him to be a non-human character.

Comment: Odd that the date on the top image says "Feb 24 **2012**". I expected early concept art to have a date from the mid-1970's.

Comment: Interesting. The early Vader art shows him with skull scars on the top of his head and under his right eye, much like we saw when Luke removed his mask at the end of *The Return of the Jedi*.

Comment: @RichS  Sorry, I should have clarified that the concept art in question was for the comic.  The comic, however, is based on the original draft of the script.  I consider this to be sufficient, as there were other characters that underwent changes by the time the film was in production (for example: Han Solo was originally a green-skinned alien creature, a member of a species known as the "Ureallians").

Comment: I found this YouTube clip about the history of the making of Darth Vader behind the scenes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmOG1wg5sVo It shows early concept art exactly as you described. :-)

Comment: @RichS  Interesting!

Comment: Not definitive. `comic, however, is based on the original draft of the script` but the much of retrofit George Lucas has done by 2012, this doesn't really mean anything. I seriously doubt the comic writers would do a comic that's entirely contradictory to the George-Lucas-version-of-canon-as-of-2012. Even if the draft contains an alien, the comic would still contain a human if that's what the canon is at the time of making the comic.

Comment: @n611x007

I'm not sure I follow. I never said that I had definitive proof, only that I found some evidence to support the conclusion that Vader was always intended to be human, and that I found no contrary evidence. My answer opens by saying "As far as I can determine..." and the closing sentence states "there doesn't seem to be anything to indicate..." These are not absolute statements. I admit that there may be evidence that I have not found.

(Space is running short here; I'll continue my response in the next comment)

Comment: @n611x007

I'm not sure I understand why long-established canon would have much of an effect on this comic. This comic is not canon. The entire point of it being released as a comic is to show us what Star Wars would have looked like had they kept Lucas' original script. As I mentioned, the original draft had Han Solo as a green-skinned alien (a member of the Ureallian species).  Established canon depicts Solo as a human.

(Running short of space again; I'll continue in the next comment)

Comment: @n611x007

Here are some other changes between the Original Draft (hereafter referred to as "OD") and the final version of Star Wars (hereafter referred to as "SW"):
OD: Vader is NOT a cyborg.
SW: Vader IS a cyborg.
OD: Luke Skywalker is already an experienced Jedi, and a General.
SW: Luke is not a Jedi, but just a young farm boy descended from a Jedi.
OD: The Jedi previously served the Empire (there was no Republic), and even served as the Emperor's bodyguards.
SW: The Jedi protected the Republic.

(Sorry, this turned out to be longer than expected; I'll finish in next comment)

Comment: @n611x007

One last example:

OD: There's a character named "Annikin" (not a typo, it was originally spelt differently), but he was not related to Luke.
SW: Anakin was Luke's father.

There are plenty of other examples, but I think that these illustrate my point.  Again, the story is not canon, so the established canon really should have no effect on what was depicted there. I'm not saying (nor have I ever said) that my evidence IS definitive, only that it's safe to go by it in the absence of contrary evidence.

(Also, sorry for the format of the last couple comments)

Answer (score 1):

In 2005, George Lucas was on the Tonight Show and said he originally had Luke be a sixty-five-year-old man, and Vader was supposed to be a character which morphed into General Grevous. Others involved in the production persuaded him to change it.

Comment: Can you provide a transcript or a video link? I bet you can find it on YouTube.